# Click event not working on option tag in angular 4

Tags: angular, internet-explorer, select

```
 const vendors = [
  {name: 'test', age: 123},
  {name: 'tes34t', age: 12233}
]


<select>
  <option *ngFor="let l of vendors" (click)="findSso(l)">{{ l }} </option>
</select>
```

My click is not working in IE, it works in chrome. How can get it to work in IE?

Comment: why not use < select #myselect (change)="findSso(myselect)" >...?

Comment: I just want the single object to print, doing #myselect will give the complete select tag with all option values.

Comment: If you only want the value, < select #myselect (change)="findSso(myselect.value)" >

Comment: i want the complete object

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of `(click)` on the `option`, go for `(change)` on the `select`. I'd recommend that as it is more performant and would only get triggered when the option is changed. And that's what we're looking for in here anyway.

Here, give this a try:

```
<select (change)="findSso($event.target.value)">
  <option value="null" disabled>Select a Vendor</option>
  <option *ngFor="let vendor of vendors" [value]="vendor.name">{{ vendor.name }} </option>
</select>
```

And in your Component:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  vendors = [
    { name: 'test', age: 123 },
    { name: 'tes34t', age: 12233 }
  ];

  findSso(selectedVendor) {
    console.log('Got the selectedVendor as : ', selectedVendor);
    // DO the needful here.
  }
}
```

---

Here's a [**Working Sample StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ccmewx?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) for your ref.

---

### UPDATE

If you want the full object to be passed, you can do something like this:

```
<select #selectList (change)="findSso(selectList.value)">
  <option value="null" disabled>Select a Vendor</option>
  <option *ngFor="let vendor of vendors" value="{{ vendor | json }}">{{ vendor.name }} </option>
</select>
```

Here we're using the [**`json`**](https://angular.io/api/common/JsonPipe) pipe to convert the Object to string.

Now in your Template, just call `JSON.parse` on the incoming argument:

```
findSso(selectedVendor) {
  console.log('Got the selectedVendor as : ', JSON.parse(selectedVendor));
}
```

The code is already present in the sample StackBlitz.

Comment: @Abhishek, glad I could help. Please consider marking one of these answers as a solution to close the loop. :)

Comment: Actually it does not work, i cannot read the complete object. its gives value undefined
If I do
    <option *ngFor="let vendor of vendors" [value]="vendor">{{ vendor}} </option>
and try to read the value of vendor.it does not come up

Comment: I actually mentioned something in Teddy's answer. Please make sure you've added `[value]="vendor.name"` to the `option` tag and while calling `findSso` on `change`, you've passed `$event.target.value`.

Comment: What if i want the complete object to be printed not just the name

Comment: The issue is, if you use `[value]="vendor"` and then on `change` call your method, it is going to receive a string `[object Object]`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185086/discussion-between-siddajmera-and-abhishek).

Answer (score 2):

`onclick` is not a valid event for an `option` tag ([see here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp)). You should use the `onchange` event on the `select` tag to get an event when a value changes. Example:

```html
<select (change)="findSso($event.value)">
  <option *ngFor="let l of vendors" [value]="l">{{ l }} </option>
</select>
```

Comment: it prints values as undefined

Comment: @Abhishek, It should have been `$event.target.value`. But even with that, it would print [object Object]. GIve my solution a try to see if that works for you.

Comment: Actually it does not work, i cannot read the complete object. its gives value undefined If I do <option *ngFor="let vendor of vendors" [value]="vendor">{{ vendor}} </option> and try to read the value of vendor.it does not come up

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `(click)` please use change event. and `[(ngModel)]` can be used for detecting changes through `ngModelChange` event.

And for `<option></option>` tag `[ngValue]` directive can take `string` or `object` and through `ngModel` we can track the change event.

```
<select [ngModel]="selectedValue" (ngModelChange)="selectedValue=$event">
  <option value="null" disabled>Select a Vendor</option>
  <option *ngFor="let vendor of vendors" [ngValue]="vendor">{{ vendor.name }} </option>
</select>
```

For Reference added [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hzxrve?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) code.

Comment: ngModel is not allowed in reactive forms

Comment: @Abhishek then we can use `[formControl]` and we can subscribe the valueChanges event of FormControl in case of ReaciveForm.